# How can I combine the same CSS properties for different elements?

Tags: css, properties

I have two elements: **tooltip** and **tooltip-line**.
There is common properties for each elements:

```
[tooltip]::after, [tooltip-line]::after  {
position: absolute;
opacity: 0;
visibility: hidden;
/* Other common properties */
}
```

Next, I have different properties for each element.

```
[tooltip-line]::after  { /* One line tooltip */
    content: attr(tooltip-line);
    white-space: nowrap;
}
[tooltip]::after  { /* Multiline tooltip */
    content: attr(tooltip);
    width: 200px;
    white-space: normal;
}
```

Is this a correct usage? Including similar classes. Or should I copy all properties to each declaration block?

Comment: can you show me the HTML code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a different approach which might be slightly more scalable. Using CSS custom variables, we can override any default class values by resetting them in the `multiline` class. Finally, I would make the attributes containing the tooltip content identical—and valid *data* attributes—if possible.

```css
.tooltip::after {
  --tooltip-white-space: nowrap;
  
  content: attr(data-tooltip-content);
  white-space: var(--tooltip-white-space);
}

.tooltip.multiline::after {
  --tooltip-white-space: normal;
}

.container {
  width: 250px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tooltip" data-tooltip-content="my tooltip content should not wrap no matter what"></div>

  <div class="tooltip multiline" data-tooltip-content="my multliline tooltip content should wrap"></div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ym102rtq/2/)

Comment: After reviewing your code, I learned about the [BEM approach](https://en.bem.info/methodology/css/#mixes). I just wanted to do everything right, according to the standards. Thanks!

Comment: @JasperScritt I've been doing this for 20+ years, and I'll tell you it's all subjective. There is no "everything right"—only opinion and experience. BEM is one way to go, but has become far less popular as web app use has skyrocketed.

Comment: So I have to name classes solely in terms of common sense? But what if these styles will be reviewed by another person? Just to make more comments inside classes?

Comment: @JasperScritt For fully vanilla CSS projects, I see the BEM use-case for sure. In a production environment, you'll likely be working with Styled Components or CSS Modules, or some system where styles are scoped to the components in which the CSS is created. This makes BEM much less useful.

Answer (score 0):

It's absolutely right to divide the *css* in multiple blocks.

One of the first thing to know while writing code in any language is **NOT** to repeat yourself.

Comment: That's right! I've been programming and have an idea about functions, but I'd like to know how to compress CSS code correctly.